# Variance of $XY(1-Y)$ in terms of the means and variances $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, variance

Consider two independent random variables X and Y. X has some distribution with mean $\mu_X$ and variance $\sigma^2_X$. Y has some distribution with mean $\mu_Y$ and variance $\sigma^2_Y$. I want to take the variance of the quantity $XY(1-Y)$. Is the correct answer:
$$\sigma^2_{XY(1-Y)} = \sigma^2_X[Y(1-Y)]^2+X^2[\sigma^2_Y(1-\sigma^2_Y)]?$$
I just did some kind of weird product rule but with variances and I'm not sure that's at all legit.

The reason I want to know the variance of this quantity is that it is a measure of the real noise in an experimental system I am working with. I am an experimental physicist and my math skills are weak at best. You might recognize the form $XY(1-Y)$ from the binomial distribution: $Np(1-p)$. My experiment does not follow a binomial distribution exactly, it follows a Poisson binomial distribution *but* with varying $N$ and $p$ for each shot of the experiment. So I need to know the variance of the quantity $XY(1-Y)$ when I know the variances and expectation values of $X$ and $Y$.

I'm trying to work this particular detail out to answer this question:
[Repeated binomial processes with different probabilities and number of trials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044515/repeated-binomial-processes-with-different-probabilities-and-number-of-trials) .

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87456/discussion-on-question-by-sabrinachoice-how-to-take-the-variance-of-a-product-of).

Comment: The formula $$\sigma^2_{XY(1-Y)} = \sigma^2_X[Y(1-Y)]^2+X^2[\sigma^2_Y(1-\sigma^2_Y)]$$ cannot be correct since $\sigma^2_{XY(1-Y)}$, $\sigma^2_X$ and $\sigma^2_Y(1-\sigma^2_Y)$ are *numbers* while $[Y(1-Y)]^2$ and $X^2$ are *random variables*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{aligned}\mathsf{Var}XY\left(1-Y\right) & =\mathsf{Covar}\left(XY\left(1-Y\right),XY\left(1-Y\right)\right)\\
 & =\mathsf{Covar}\left(XY-XY^{2},XY-XY^{2}\right)\\
 & =\mathsf{Var}\left(XY\right)-2\mathsf{Covar}\left(XY^{2},XY\right)+\mathsf{Var}\left(XY^{2}\right)\\
 & =\left[\mathbb{E}X^{2}Y^{2}-\left(\mathbb{E}XY\right)^{2}\right]-2\left[\mathbb{E}X^{2}Y^{3}-\mathbb{E}XY^{2}\mathbb{E}XY\right]+\left[\mathbb{E}X^{2}Y^{4}-\left(\mathbb{E}XY^{2}\right)^{2}\right]\\
 & =\left[\mathbb{E}X^{2}\mathbb{E}Y^{2}-\left(\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y\right)^{2}\right]-2\left[\mathbb{E}X^{2}\mathbb{E}Y^{3}-\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y^{2}\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y\right]+\left[\mathbb{E}X^{2}\mathbb{E}Y^{4}-\left(\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y^{2}\right)^{2}\right]\\
 & =\left[\mathbb{E}X^{2}\mathbb{E}Y^{2}-\mu_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}^{2}\right]-2\left[\mathbb{E}X^{2}\mathbb{E}Y^{3}-\mu_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}\mathbb{E}Y^{2}\right]+\left[\mathbb{E}X^{2}\mathbb{E}Y^{4}-\mu_{X}^{2}\left(\mathbb{E}Y^{2}\right)^{2}\right]\\
 & =\left[\left(\sigma_{X}^{2}+\mu_{X}^{2}\right)\left(\sigma_{Y}^{2}+\mu_{Y}^{2}\right)-\mu_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}^{2}\right]-2\left[\left(\sigma_{X}^{2}+\mu_{X}^{2}\right)\mathbb{E}Y^{3}-\mu_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}\left(\sigma_{Y}^{2}+\mu_{Y}^{2}\right)\right]+\left[\left(\sigma_{X}^{2}+\mu_{X}^{2}\right)\mathbb{E}Y^{4}-\mu_{X}^{2}\left(\sigma_{Y}^{2}+\mu_{Y}^{2}\right)^{2}\right]\\
 & =\left[\sigma_{X}^{2}\sigma_{Y}^{2}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}^{2}+\sigma_{Y}^{2}\mu_{X}^{2}\right]-2\left[\left(\sigma_{X}^{2}+\mu_{X}^{2}\right)\mathbb{E}Y^{3}-\mu_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}\left(\sigma_{Y}^{2}+\mu_{Y}^{2}\right)\right]+\left[\left(\sigma_{X}^{2}+\mu_{X}^{2}\right)\mathbb{E}Y^{4}-\mu_{X}^{2}\left(\sigma_{Y}^{2}+\mu_{Y}^{2}\right)^{2}\right]
\end{aligned}
$

Especially the $5$-th equality rests on independence of $X$ and $Y$.

We cannot get any further since for the expressions $\mathbb EY^3$ and $\mathbb EY^4$ more information is needed concerning the distribution of $Y$.

---

**edit**:

Special case: $Y\sim\mathsf{Normal}\left(\mu_{Y},\sigma_{Y}^{2}\right)$.

Then $Y=\mu_{Y}+\sigma_{Y}U$ where $U\sim\mathsf{Normal}\left(0,1\right)$
and based on the knowledge that $\mathbb{E}U^{3}=0$ and $\mathbb{E}U^{4}=3$
we find:

- $\mathbb{E}Y^{3}=\mathbb{E}\left(\mu_{Y}^{3}+3\mu_{Y}^{2}\sigma_{Y}U+3\mu_{Y}\sigma_{Y}^{2}U^{2}+\sigma_{Y}^{3}U^{3}\right)=\mu_{Y}^{3}+3\mu_{Y}\sigma_{Y}^{2}$
- $\mathbb{E}Y^{4}=\mathbb{E}\left(\mu_{Y}^{4}+4\mu_{Y}^{3}\sigma_{Y}U+6\mu_{Y}^{2}\sigma_{Y}^{2}U^{2}+4\mu_{Y}\sigma_{Y}^{3}U^{3}+\sigma_{Y}^{4}U^{4}\right)=\mu_{Y}^{4}+6\mu_{Y}^{2}\sigma_{Y}^{2}+3\sigma_{Y}^{4}$

Also have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) for that.

Substituting we find the following expression for $\mathsf{Var}XY\left(1-Y\right)$:

$$\left[\sigma_{X}^{2}\sigma_{Y}^{2}+\sigma_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}^{2}+\sigma_{Y}^{2}\mu_{X}^{2}\right]-2\left[\sigma_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}^{3}+3\sigma_{X}^{2}\sigma_{Y}^{2}\mu_{Y}+2\sigma_{Y}^{2}\mu_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}\right]+\left[\sigma_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}^{4}+6\sigma_{X}^{2}\sigma_{Y}^{2}\mu_{Y}^{2}+3\sigma_{X}^{2}\sigma_{Y}^{4}+4\sigma_{Y}^{2}\mu_{X}^{2}\mu_{Y}^{2}+2\sigma_{Y}^{4}\mu_{X}^{2}\right]$$

I hope I did not make any mistakes (check me on it).

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you! I wouldn't have thought of taking the covariance first. I'm not actually sure about the exact distributions of X and Y (they will be empirically determined). They'll probably end up Gaussian. Once I know them, then I would just have to do the integrals. Thanks so much, this is really helpful.

Comment: @SabrinaChoice: In general, you can try to look at the moments of any sufficiently nice distribution if they exist, and each moment is a separate 'degree of freedom'. In fact, if all finite moments exist, then they uniquely characterize the distribution (if it has a continuous CDF). So we can also compare distributions by comparing their moments.

Comment: @SabrinaChoice I let you know that I found a mistake (and repaired). $\mathbb EX^2\mathbb EX^2$ was accidently replaced by $\sigma_X^2+\mu_X^2$, but had to be replaced by $(\sigma_X^2+\mu_X^2)(\sigma_Y^2+\mu_Y^2)$ of course.

Comment: In my former comment $\mathbb EX^2\mathbb EX^2$ should be $\mathbb EX^2\mathbb EY^2$. Also I edited for the special case that $Y$ takes normal distribution.

Comment: @drhab I finally had the chance to go through this carefully and check for errors. I couldn't find any. Thank you very much, I really appreciate it. My math skills are weak, but I feel like this particular example will make me much better equipped to solve a problem like this on my own next time I encounter one.

Comment: @drhab there's a small typo in the special case, the second bullet point should read $\mathbb{E}(Y^4)$

Comment: Typo is repaired. Glad to help.